# Create a Angular resizable horizontal Card

Tags: css, angular, resizable

I am following this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizable?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) to create a resizable angular card layout like the image below.
[resizable card layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTNrw.png)
Here when I drag the top header to right or left the size of card content along with header need to be resized but my problem here the drag property does not working in my code

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" [resizableMinWidth]=30 appResizable>
      SNO
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" [resizableMinWidth]=30 appResizable>
      Name
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" [resizableMinWidth]=30 appResizable>
      Desigination
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        01
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        Sam
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        SE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Comment: Please check the link [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizable-zdajyw?file=app%2Fapp.component.css). UI is not 100% accurate as you asked but you can try.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add your directive to your module? it is important add the ResizableDirective in the part of the declarations which belongs to your module.ts
   `@NgModule({ imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], declarations: [ AppComponent, ResizableDirective ], bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ] })`
Please let me know if is not the case to find another reason. :) It would be great if you include your stacktrace and also your files .ts

Comment: Please check the stackblitz link @RSubash already provided.

Comment: I had added the directive

Comment: The stackblitz link is the example that you are following, to be able to help you I will need to check your own implementation and also If you send me your stack trace It will be grateful

Comment: This is the Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-adflfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You need to change your container flex-direction from column to row and add the others styles for each divs this will allows the resizable function but you will have to fix the layout `.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
  background: lightblue;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
  background: green;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.div3 {
  position: relative;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
  background: pink;
  flex-grow:0;
}`

Comment: This is because the pipeline use the col-resize property and this only works for columns and with rows not, you can read the following documentation https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp it will help you undertand that properties and with that you wll be able to edit or create your own implemention for resizable rows

Comment: Ok @gisshizuku45. I will try to implement it.

Comment: I'm trying grow up my new account to be able to add comments if mark this answer as useful It would be great :D